# ControlsFX LineBorder with title has white background rather than transparent

Tags: java, border, javafx-8, controlsfx

So when I make a ControlsFX titled border surrounding whatever I get this weird glitch:

[image]

See the white area around the 'hi'? That isn't suppose to be there. The weird thing is if I add the same border (new instance) to another `Tab`, then it becomes normal:

[image]

Here is the code to generate the border:

```
Node calculateBorderd2 = Borders.wrap(new TextField()).etchedBorder().title("hi").buildAll();
bottomBorderPane.setRight(calculateBordered2);
```

This is reproducible only in my program. I tried to create mcve, but as said, I was unable to reproduce it. Adding the second border 100% fixes the issue (not a sometimes thing).

I am pretty sure this is a bug either in JavaFX or ControlsFX. I looked through all my code and couldn't find anything that could remotely relate to this (but obviously there is). I am using half and half FXML.

I looked into the decompiled `Borders` class and found that the background is generated as transparent, and something else if scene is not equal to null:

```
private void updateTitleLabelFill() {
    Scene s = n.getScene();
    if(s == null) {
    BackgroundFill fill = new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, (CornerRadii)null, (Insets)null);
    this.titleLabel.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill[]{fill}));
    } else {
        this.updateTitleLabelFillFromScene(s);
        s.fillProperty().addListener(new WeakInvalidalionListener(this.updateTitleListener));
     }
}

private void updateTitleLabelFillFromScene(Scene s) {
    s.snapshot(new Callback() {
        public Void call(SnapshotResult result) {
            WritableImage image = result.getImage();
            PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();
            int start = (int)titleLabel.getLocalToSceneTransform().getTx();
            int finish = (int)((double)start + titleLabel.getWidth());
            int startY = (int)titleLabel.getLocalToSceneTransform().getTy();
            int finishY = (int)((double)startY + titleLabel.getHeight());
            HashMap map = new HashMap();

            Color color;
            for(int max = startY; max < finishY; ++max) {
                for(int column = start; column < finish; ++column) {
                    try {
                        color = reader.getColor(column, max);
                        if(map.containsKey(color)) {
                            map.put(color, Integer.valueOf(((Integer)map.get(color)).intValue() + 1));
                         } else {
                             map.put(color, Integer.valueOf(1));
                         }
                     } catch (Exception var14) {
                         ;
                     }
                 }
             }

             double var15 = 0.0D;
             color = null;
             Iterator fill = map.keySet().iterator();

             while(fill.hasNext()) {
                 Color colorTemp = (Color)fill.next();
                 if((double)((Integer)map.get(colorTemp)).intValue() > var15) {
                     color = colorTemp;
                     var15 = (double)((Integer)map.get(colorTemp)).intValue();
                 }
             }

             BackgroundFill var16 = new BackgroundFill(color, (CornerRadii)null, (Insets)null);
             titleLabel.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill[]{var16}));
             return null;
         }
     }, (WritableImage)null);
 }
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before? If you want to see my whole code (tens of classes), I could add you to my BitBucket repo to view it all.

Answer (score 0):

Where is situated your titled Border?

Like it is shown in https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/441/background-color-of-borders-is-incorrect , the background is computed directly.

So if your border is moving, or appearing above another thing, we may have the problem of picking the wrong color. I will fix that soon in ControlsFX